# Why SharePoint 2013 keep ask me credential when I click 'Manage web applications' in Central Administration

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, login, credentials

I have a virtual machine which is Windows Server 2012 and Sharepoint 2013.

This is what I did:

•         Log in the box 
•         Open the sharepoint central admin , 
•         Click ‘Manage web applications’ under Application management. It pop up the window to ask me to type the credential. Regardless I type it my credential or not, it always failed.

The weird thing is it's fine if log in from outside the box, for example, I log in from another machine by using browser. I have no problem at all.

Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you open Central Admin by using the Central Admin icon or by typing the url in the address bar of your browser?

Answer (score 0):

couple of things

- make sure you access the Central admin on the server using fully qualified name, not short name
- [disable the loopback](http://sp-vinod.blogspot.com/2013/03/disable-loop-back-check-in-sharepoint.html) check on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I fixed this issue by below step: log in Central Central by running IE as admin, then add me into the SharePoint central admin group.